# Incremental counter and array.count giving inconsistent answers when using dispatch queue

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, cocoa-touch, grand-central-dispatch

I have a simple app that retrieves the last 7 days data split by hour (168 records) from CMPedometer and stores them in an array. I then go through that array to find the highest distance travelled in the array and display this in a label on a view.

```
    var GlobalMainQueue: dispatch_queue_t {
        return dispatch_get_main_queue()
    }
    var exerciseDataGroup = dispatch_group_create()
    dispatch_group_enter(exerciseDataGroup)
    var modelController = ModelController.init()
    dispatch_group_leave(exerciseDataGroup)


    dispatch_group_notify(exerciseDataGroup, GlobalMainQueue){
        self.BestHourOfTheWeekLabel.text = "Your best distance of the last 7 days was \(modelController.getHighestHourInWeek())"
        }
```

The above code is in my viewDidLoad method. In the modelController initializer I run getDistanceForEachHourInWeek() to retrieve all the distance records and populate an array to hold them.

```
func getDistanceForEachHourInWeek(){
    //****TESTING****
    var count = 0
    var errorCount = 0

    for day in 0...7 {
        //Getting Todays Date
        var today = NSDate()
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        //breaking date into components
        var requestedTodaysDateComponents: NSCalendarUnit = .CalendarUnitYear |
            .CalendarUnitMonth |
            .CalendarUnitDay |
            .CalendarUnitHour |
            .CalendarUnitMinute
        var todaysDateComponents = calendar.components(requestedTodaysDateComponents,
            fromDate: today)
        //modifying components to get required date from past 7 days
        todaysDateComponents.day = todaysDateComponents.day - day
        var requestDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(todaysDateComponents)

        for hour in 01...24 {
        //getting start and finish times
        var beginningOfDay = getDateForDaysAgo(day, hour: hour, minutes: 00)
        var endOfDay = getDateForDaysAgo(day, hour: hour, minutes: 59)

        //create a distanceRecord instance for each day
        var recordActivity = distanceRecord.init(startDate: beginningOfDay, endDate: endOfDay)

        //populate the dustanceRecord with data
        self.Pedometer.queryPedometerDataFromDate(beginningOfDay, toDate: endOfDay, withHandler: {activity, error in
            if (error != nil){
                NSLog(" \(error.localizedDescription)")
                ++errorCount
            }
            else{
                //*****TESTING
                ++count
                NSLog("\(count)")
                //add the step counting data
                recordActivity.stepCount = activity.numberOfSteps
                //add the distance data
                recordActivity.distance = activity.distance
                self.hourlyDistanceRecordArray.append(sigActivity)
            }
        })
        }
    }
    NSLog("Finished getting hours, \(count) records & \(errorCount) errors")
}
```

Below is the function called to update the label in the viewDidLoad method.

```
func getHighestHourInWeek() -> String {
    var itemsInArray = hourlyDistanceRecordArray.count
    NSLog("\(hourlyDistanceRecordArray.count)")
    var highestValue: Float = 0.0
    var highestDistanceRecord = distanceRecord(startDate: NSDate(), endDate: NSDate())
    for index in 0...itemsInArray {
        if hourlyDistanceRecordArray[index].distance.floatValue > highestValue {
            highestValue = hourlyDistanceRecordArray[index].distance.floatValue
            highestDistanceRecord = hourlyDistanceRecordArray[index]
        }
    }
    return highestDistanceRecord.distance.stringValue
}
```

The problem I have is that the incremental count in the getDistanceForEachHourInWeek() NSLog statement gives me one figure, the array.count in the getHighestHourInWeek() NSLog gives me another different usually higher figure and neither equals 168 records that I'm expecting and it's also not consistent in the figures it gives me each time I run it. I tried to resolve it using dispatch queues but it hasn't helped.

My NSLog statements give me the results (shortened):

```
1
2
3
...
15
Finished getting hours, 15 records & 0 errors
16
17
18
...
192
```

Can anyone help point me where I have gone wrong? Why is the code not waiting until it's finished the for loop before it moves on?

Comment: Maybe you should post the code that shows how you get different counts.  What you have here doesn't look like it's related to the question.

Comment: thanks. I've added the additional code.

Comment: You may find the culprit if you know the correct answer to the question "Is the Initialiser of `ModelController` asynchronous or synchronous?"

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Here's my code, it's a subclass of NSObject   `override init(){
        //Check if distance logging is available
        self.Pedometer = CMPedometer()
        super.init()
        self.getStepsForTheWeek()
        self.getDistanceForEachHourInWeek()
        }` how do i tell if its synch or asynch?

Comment: Well, I suspect `self.Pedometer.queryPedometerDataFromDate ` is asynchronous. Thus, since asynchronicity is infectious, the _calling_ function (`init`) becomes asynchronous as well. A function is "asynchronous" when its effect visible to the call-site may occur _after_ the function returns to the caller. Take a closer look to your sample, you might see that your access `modelController.getHighestHourInWeek()` might occur _before_ this value has been evaluated.

Comment: Just read the class reference and that method does run asynchronously. I'm guessing there's no way of forcing this to run synchronously so I was thinking of having some form of notification when the array has hit the number of records I'm expecting that then refreshes the view. Does this seem sensible or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using NSNotification.

In my ModelController initializer I added

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "arrayPopulated", name: arrayPopulated, object: nil)
```

I modified getDistanceForEachHourInWeek function in my ModelController so that the pedometer call checked to see if I had as many records in my array as I was expecting (24 x 7 = 168)

```
self.Pedometer.queryPedometerDataFromDate(beginningOfDay, toDate: endOfDay, withHandler: {activity, error in
                    if (error != nil){
                        NSLog(" \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        NSLog("ERROR")
                        ++errorCount
                    }
                    else{
                        //XXXXXXXXTESTINGXXXXXXXX
                        ++count
                        tempActivity.stepCount = activity.numberOfSteps
                        //add the distance data
                        tempActivity.distance = activity.distance
                        //Append the tempActivity instance to myActivityArray
                        self.hourlyDistanceRecordArray.append(tempActivity)
                        if count == 168 {
                            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(self.arrayPopulated, object: self)
                        }
                    }
                })
```

then caught the notification in my viewDidLoad function of my viewController

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "actOnArrayPopulated", name: "arrayPopulated", object: nil)
```

and put all my label updates in the function

```
func actOnArrayPopulated() {
    NSLog("Notification received")
    self.updateScreen()
}
```

I still seem to have a lag between my notification being received and my screen being updated but its progress